KeyboardInterrupt in asyncio.TaskGroup
The docs on Task Groups say:

Two base exceptions are treated specially: If any task fails with KeyboardInterrupt or SystemExit, the task group still cancels the remaining tasks and waits for them, but then the initial KeyboardInterrupt or SystemExit is re-raised instead of ExceptionGroup or BaseExceptionGroup.

This makes me believe, given the following code:
import asyncio

async def task():
    await asyncio.sleep(10)

async def run() -> None:
    try:
        async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
            t1 = tg.create_task(task())
            t2 = tg.create_task(task())
        print("Done")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Stopped")

asyncio.run(run())

running and hitting Ctrl-C should result in printing Stopped; but in fact, the exception is not caught:
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "<python>/asyncio/runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<python>/asyncio/base_events.py", line 685, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<module>/__init__.py", line 8, in run
    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
  File "<python>/asyncio/taskgroups.py", line 134, in __aexit__
    raise propagate_cancellation_error
  File "<python>/asyncio/taskgroups.py", line 110, in __aexit__
    await self._on_completed_fut
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 189, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 148, in _get_module_details
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 112, in _get_module_details
  File "<module>/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    asyncio.run(run())
  File "<python>/asyncio/runners.py", line 194, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<python>/asyncio/runners.py", line 123, in run
    raise KeyboardInterrupt()
KeyboardInterrupt

What am I missing? What is the correct way of detecting KeyboardInterrupt?

Oh btw also might be useful to read this SO answer - I didn't know asyncio.TaskGroup was this fragile, guess it's really not doing well against anyio or trio

TL;DR
This acutally isn't TaskGroup's fault. Try running this:
>>> async def other_task():
...     try:
...         await asyncio.sleep(10)
...     except KeyboardInterrupt:
...         print("Stopped")
>>>
>>> asyncio.run(other_task())
KeyboardInterrupt

>>>

This also doesn't print. Nor this:
>>> async def other_task():
...     try:
...         await asyncio.sleep(10)
...     except Exception as err:
...         print("Stopped by", err)
>>>
>>> asyncio.run(other_task())
KeyboardInterrupt

>>>

You can't catch KeyboardInterrupt here.
I can't say I know exactly why, but can say this is why asyncio.shield is useless protecting tasks from canceling, that it requires one to write our own signal handlers for asyncio because task cancellation internally triggers KeyboardInterrupt.


Alternative way

trio - made by Nathaniel J. Smith who first came up with modern Structured concurrency - does clearly what you intended.
# NOTE: somehow ctrl+c doesn't work in ptpython. Following ran on default python shell

# Python 3.12.1 (tags/v3.12.1:2305ca5, Dec  7 2023, 22:03:25) [MSC v.1937 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>>> import trio
>>> async def task():
...     await trio.sleep(5)
...
>>> async def run():
...     try:
...         async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
...             for _ in range(10):
...                 nursery.start_soon(task)
...     except* KeyboardInterrupt:
...         print("Nursery caught KeyboardInterrupt!")
...
>>> trio.run(run)
Nursery caught KeyboardInterrupt!
>>>

# Python 3.11.2 (main, Mar 13 2023, 12:18:29) [GCC 12.2.0] on linux
>>> import trio
>>> from exceptiongroup import catch
>>> async def task():
...     await trio.sleep(5)
...
>>> async def run():
...     def handle_keyboard_interrupt(excgroup):
...         nonlocal nursery
...         print("Nursery caught KeyboardInterrupt!")
...         nursery.cancel_scope.cancel()
...
...     with catch({KeyboardInterrupt: handle_keyboard_interrupt}):
...         async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
...             for _ in range(10):
...                 nursery.start_soon(task)
...
>>> trio.run(run)
^CNursery caught KeyboardInterrupt!
>>>

which is not callback soup unlike asyncio, making it much more stable and intuitive, predictive. (Not saying asyncio is trash; it was the right option when it was created.)
So definitely check out trio when what you're trying to make requires such. asyncio.TaskGroup is just asyncio's attempt of Structured Concurrency achieved by trio.Nursery and original does it's job better than asyncio which inevitably suffer from internals being callback soup.
Edit: Also you can use trio-asyncio or such wrappers to run asyncio loop on the trio, or mix thread-based libraries with trio


More details

To why this happens, this is the hint:
>>> async def sync_task():
...     try:
...         time.sleep(10)
...     except KeyboardInterrupt:
...         print("Stopping")

>>> asyncio.run(sync_task())
Stopping
KeyboardInterrupt

If we intentionally block the thread by time.sleep() call, it do catches the KeyboardInterrupt. (Despite asyncio also re-raise again)
Which is just same as this.
>>> def sync_task():
...     try:
...         time.sleep(10)
...     except KeyboardInterrupt:
...         print("Stopping")
>>> sync_task()
Stopping

Now we established that we do can catch KeyboardInterrupt in synchronous code section regardless of the surroundings being async context or not.
Then we can draw the attention back to:

Is await asyncio.sleep(10) synchronous?

And this might sound obvious, it's not!
...But then, What is being executed if it's not synchronous?

That's the core reason why asyncio can't catch a thing on KeyboardInterrupt. Because it's not our task, but the main thread that's consistently checking if certain event should be triggered or not.
In other words, we just killed the main loop by KeyboardInterrupt while our tasks are suspended, waiting for main thread's loop to call it's callback for event "Call me AFTER 10 seconds are passed". Hence there was no chance for our poor task to ever catch that exception.
This is because unlike other exceptions that is Returned as Result of task (then probably re-thrown at await keyword), KeyboardInterrupt is an urgent exception signaling to stop whatever we're doing, so event loop decide to stop and start doing cleanup if possible.


Way more detail about Callback-based vs async/await native

To quote from Control-C handling in Python and Trio by Nathaniel J. Smith :

By default, the Python interpreter sets things up so that control-C will cause a KeyboardInterrupt exception to materialize at some point in your code.
This is pretty nice! If your code was accidentally caught in an infinite loop, then it breaks out of that. If you have cleanup code in finally blocks, it gets run. It shows a traceback so you can find that infinite loop.
That's the advantage of the KeyboardInterrupt approach: even if you didn't think about control-C at all while you were writing the program, then it still does something that's pretty darn reasonable – say, 99% of the time.
lock.acquire()
try:
    do_stuff()             # <-
    do_something_else()    # <- control-C anywhere here is safe
    and_some_more()        # <-
finally:
    lock.release()

But what if we're unlucky?
lock.acquire()
                           # <- control-C could happen here
try:
    ...
finally:
                           # <- or here
    lock.release()

If a KeyboardInterrupt happens at one of the two points marked above, then sucks to be us: the exception will propagate but our lock will never be released.


... KeyboardInterrupt is such powerful and dangerous message to Python - it's not mere simple Exception but is almost like a SIGINT for python. (On windows task kill triggers KeyboardInterrupt because it doesn't have SIGINT)

This is the major disadvantage of Callback-based Concurrency we had for years on Javascript and many others, including python's future and asyncio.
From python's history of 1991~2015:

Python 1.0 release (Python 1, 1991)

Asyncore library (Python 1, 1996)

Callback based


Generator support added (Python 2.2, 2001)

Twisted (Python 2.X, 2002)

Easier concurrency programming via Generator


Generator.send() support added (Python 2.5, 2005)

Now generator can 'talk' with caller


Future library (Python 3.2, 2011)

asyncio library (Python 3.4, 2014)

generator based, wraps Future
Best of the bests from previous libraries


async / await added (Python 3.5, 2015)



asyncio was never designed with async / await in mind - but is based on callbacks like recent Javascript does. (Initial javascript release at 1995 didn't have concurrency iirc)
So how we use asyncio with async / await nowdays are under-the-hood a complete hybrid mess trying to make callback soup work on something fundamentally different.

When we call asyncio.run(async_func) - it runs in this order:
# NOTE: all comment with ^^^^^^ prefix are my comments explaining relevant parts


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
# asyncio/runners.py

def run(main, *, debug=None, loop_factory=None):
    ...
    
    with Runner(debug=debug, loop_factory=loop_factory) as runner:
        return runner.run(main)
        # ^^^^^ entry point


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
# asyncio/runners.py

class Runner:
    ...
    
    def run(self, coro, *, context=None):
        """Run a coroutine inside the embedded event loop."""
        
        ...
        
        task = self._loop.create_task(coro, context=context)
        # ^^^^^^ All async funcs are wrapped in task and is immediately pending for execution

        if (threading.current_thread() is threading.main_thread()
            and signal.getsignal(signal.SIGINT) is signal.default_int_handler
        ):
            # ^^^^^^ First hint of asyncio's internals being thread based
            
            sigint_handler = functools.partial(self._on_sigint, main_task=task)
        else:
            sigint_handler = None
        
        self._interrupt_count = 0
        try:
            return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
            # ^^^^^ entry point
        
        except exceptions.CancelledError:
            if self._interrupt_count > 0:
                uncancel = getattr(task, "uncancel", None)
                if uncancel is not None and uncancel() == 0:
                    raise KeyboardInterrupt()
                    # ^^^^^^ This is why KeyboardInterrupt raises from task cancelation
            
            raise  # CancelledError
        finally:
            ...


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
# asyncio/base_events.py
# This file and class is abstract; Actual Loops depends on OS
# due to difference event handling method per OS.


class BaseEventLoop(events.AbstractEventLoop):
    def run_until_complete(self, future):
        ...
        
        new_task = not futures.isfuture(future)
        future = tasks.ensure_future(future, loop=self)
        ...
        
        future.add_done_callback(_run_until_complete_cb)
        # ^^^^^^ Another hint of callback soup
        
        try:
            self.run_forever()
            # ^^^^^ entry point
        ...

    ...

    def run_forever(self):
        """Run until stop() is called."""
        ...
        try:
            self._thread_id = threading.get_ident()
            ...
            
            while True:
                self._run_once()
                # ^^^^^^ entry point (complex callback & event checks, skipping)
                
                if self._stopping:
                    break
        ...

Quite complex, it revolves around the callback and we can't find direct point where task actually get executed - even in self._run_once() it's just Runner class triggering enqueued event listeners.
No wonder this has so many bugs and stability issues, making us awe on how much effort could've gone into django, flask, fastAPI and etc to make it work with great stability.

To quote Some thoughts on asynchronous API design in a post-async/await world again from NJS:

Review and summing up: what is "async/await-native" anyway?
In previous asynchronous APIs for Python, the use of callback-oriented programming led to the invention of a whole set of conventions that effectively make up an entire ad hoc programming language...
The result is somewhat analogous to the bad old days before structured programming, where basic constructs like function calls and loops had to be constructed on the fly out of primitive tools like goto.
In practice, it's extraordinarily difficult to write correct code in this style, especially when one starts to think about edge conditions.
Now that Python has async/await, it's possible to start using Python's native mechanisms to solve these problems.


Such limitation of asyncio, and seeing how effective curio was - seemed to lead NJS finalizing concept of Structured Concurrency and created trio, opening path for python a bright future without future!

(Actual image attached in *Some thoughts on asynchronous API design in a post-async/await world)
I can't say I'm expert, but from my testing: A simple remote-python-execution-shell server attached to discord (Yes I actually sacrificed my Raspberry Pi here) virtually same code in asyncio died every 1 week, while trio rewrite never died over 3 months.


Is asyncio trash then

No, I think that was the best library we had when it came out, and still until we got trio. I believe trio was possible because there was asyncio!
To quote Some thoughts on asynchronous API design in a post-async/await world again & again from NJS:

Should asyncio be "fixed" to have a curio-style async/await-native API?
I can't see how this could be done without substantially throwing out and rewriting most of asyncio.
...
but the callback chaining parts are pretty deeply baked into asyncio as it currently exists.

Seems like it's now too late to rewrite it, also considering it being in standard near decade - but I do wish asyncio stop trying to mimic Structured Concurrency like recent addition of TaskGroup and rather do rewrite or deprecate in favor of other libraries - but since it's not feasible they're adding it to at least improve the current situation I suppose.
Still serves just fine on many simple usecases anyway!

If you can't catch it, what is the purpose of KeyboardInterrupt being re-raised?

@Amadan sorry brb soon - company breaks over!

@Amadan sorry took some time, btw may I ask you how familiar you are with asyncio and it's internals? answer might get way longer depending on your understanding of asyncio's internals which I kinda vaguely think you already know of.

Consider me a noob (I am way more comfortable with JavaScript tasks than Python's). BTW, I did take a quick look at trio, and I've read "Go statement consodered harmful", and I think I will try to adopt it, but: 1) when I run your code, the exception is not getting caught either (the outermost exception seems to be exceptiongroup.BaseExceptionGroup, not KeyboardInterrupt), and 2) I would still be curious as to why my code doesn't work properly (or, for that matter, why I can't make your code work either). If you have time, of course. (Tested on Python 3.10.14, trio 0.25.0.)

@Amadan great! Oh and about exceptiongroup.BaseExceptionGroup this could be my trio being outdated or some race condition. Unlike asyncio (kinda sorry to their devs to keep punching it) trio Do handle multiple errors of underlying tasks. Which means - if multiple child tasks raises all throws are nicely packed inside trio.MultiError iirc. Maybe I stopped too early and only got one throw, will update that part as well, gimme 1 hour for prep!

I think I found it, after some more time with the docs. Now by default even single exceptions create exception groups (and the option not to do it is apparently being deprecated). I don't think all of the libraries I will need to use will be able to handle 3.11, so no except* for me... so I guess I have to learn to use exceptiongroup library.

@Amadan I'm not gonna let you mark accepted and go without full context of the situation! Took waaaay longer than excepted but finally updated to full extent!

Wow, this is as lot! It will take me some time to digest. But at least I know how to write it in trio now. And you're right, it is so much simpler. I can only apologise that your hard work will go unrewarded, I already spent my one upvote :D

@Amadan When I saw you already searched and went on to read Go statement consodered harmful Which I didn't even linked yet - I immediately knew you have passion and non of my time is unrewarded for such people! Enjoy Structured Concurrency, fellow pythonista! (btw individual child task in nursery also can catch KeyboardInterrupt naturally and predictably without ExceptionGroup)

The reason you get a stack trace is because asyncio.run() uses a custom signal handler to catch KeyboardInterrupt and instead raises asyncio.CancelledError in the main task.
To quote directly from the docs (Python 3.11):

When signal.SIGINT is raised by Ctrl-C, the custom signal handler cancels the main task by calling asyncio.Task.cancel() which raises asyncio.CancelledError inside the main task. This causes the Python stack to unwind, try/except and try/finally blocks can be used for resource cleanup. After the main task is cancelled, asyncio.Runner.run() raises KeyboardInterrupt.

This means you should handle asyncio.CancelledError instead of KeyboardInterrupt:
import asyncio


async def task():
    await asyncio.sleep(10)


async def run() -> None:
    try:
        async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
            t1 = tg.create_task(task())
            t2 = tg.create_task(task())
        print("Done")
    except asyncio.CancelledError: # instead of KeyboardInterrupt
        print("Stopped")


asyncio.run(run())

Pressing CtrlC prints Stopped without the stack trace.
^CStopped

